# Google Map causes unrelated part of page to dissapear in Safari

Tags: css, google-maps, z-index

I am writting a google map using V3 of the API, into my page which results in a completley unrelated part of the page disappearing only in safai.

If you look at this page http://local.stv.tv/bellshill/ the blue navigation bar is fine, yet when you go to any page with a google map on it, part of the navigation dissapears e.g. http://local.stv.tv/bellshill/news/.

There is a dropdown in there and some layering going on which I think may be confusing Safari, but it works fine everywere else.  This must be a recent issue as the site was X browser tested fully before launch.

Comment: Looks fine to me on Safari 4. Did you fix the issue?

Comment: No. I think it's related to the latest version of safari. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue.

The primary nav `<div>` has a `<p>` element as its first item that contined a hidden skip link.  When I moved the `<p>` outside of the `<div>` everything worked fine.

To be honsest I have no idea what the real root of this problem is or why it was only Safari V5 that was effected.

Comment: please check this answer as the right one. I'm very happy i stumbled upon this :P

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem with Safari 5 on iPhone and & iPad - my contact page has location map using Google Map API

after reading post i placed my replaced the H1 tag with a span tag and it fixed the problem. maybe because the H1 is a block level element and span is an inline.

as i wanted to keep the h1 tag my final solution was to place the H1 tag inside a div tag and this seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the z-index declaration to your parent  containing the Google map to exorcise the gremlins from your machine.

```
.js-on #google-map {
  z-index:1;
}
```